# Can I sell this patented product outside the US?

Tags: claims, patent-infringment

I'm trying to reproduce this product: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160324283A1/en but I wondered if I could sell it outside the US since it has the WO patent... Thanks!

Comment: The linked file is an application, not yet a patent. Also, I’m guessing the inventor also filed internationally too.

Answer (score 1):

That number is the publication number of a U.S. patent application. It is not a granted patent at this time. Looking in the USPTO database Public PAIR, I see that it got a "final rejection" recently. That doesn't mean final; just final until more money is paid to a Request for Continued Publication. From the same database, the PCT application (WO2016179586) is shown as getting priority from US provisional application 14/706,019 filed 05-07-2015. I do not see in Patentscope (WIPO) that any national stage was entered within the 30 or 31 month time frames so the U.S. might be the only place with something pending.

Patent rights are territorial so if a U.S. patent was issued you would be prohibited from making, selling, offering for sale, using, or importing it into the US - only. What this way of looking at the situation misses is that there may be patents in any location that are already granted to this inventor of some other inventor that would constrain your actions in the respective locations.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to George White answer I would like to add that, if you are trying to reproduce the product in US and then export to other countries then also you would be liable as an infringer **if the patent gets granted** .